# jQuery copying content between DIVs

Tags: jquery, copying

I am working on a website that I want to be entirely Javascript based: you load the website, then all the pages are pulled in by Javascript.

So I here's what I have:

```
    <span id="deathWormButton">Death Worm</span>
    <div id="pageContent">
        <p>Thanks for taking the time to view my portfolio!</p>
        <p>Placeholder content</p>
        <p>Placeholder content</p>
        <p>Placeholder content</p>
        <p>Placeholder content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="DeathWormPage" class="page">
        <p>Thanks for taking the time to view my portfolio!</p>
        <p>Placeholder content</p>
        <p>Placeholder content</p>
        <p>Placeholder content</p>
        <p>Placeholder content</p>
    </div>
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $(".page").hide();
        });
        $("#deathWormButton").click(function()
        {
            $("#pageContent").innerHTML = $("#DeathWormPage").innerHTML;
        });
```

But it doesn't work! (View [here](http://portfolio.theadamgaskins.com/Portfolio))

So how do I copy content from the `div id="DeathWormPage"` into `div id="pageContent"` when the `deathWormButton` is clicked?

Comment: I'm just curious why you want to do this.  Wouldn't `$("#deathWormButton").click(function() { $("#DeathWormPage").show(); });` do what you need?

Comment: Yes, touche. It would probably look better too. Maybe I'll go with this....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jquery objects do not have an innerHTML property.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".page").hide();

    $("#deathWormButton").click(function () {
        $("#pageContent").html($("#DeathWormPage").html())
    })
});
```

Also, put it inside the document ready function or you are referencing a non-existant thing.

Comment: I think it should be `$("#pageContent").html($("#DeathWormPage").html());` eh?

Comment: This, and a typo fix, fixed the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can either do:

```
$("#pageContent").html($("#DeathWormPage").html())
```

Or

```
$("#pageContent")[0].innerHTML = $("#DeathWormPage")[0].innerHTML;
```

The later approach gets you actual DOM element for which `innerHTML` is available.

Answer (score 2):

This works to transfer the content of one div to the other div... good luck

```
body               { font-size: 16px; line-height: 2em;}
.deathWormButton   { border: 2px solid blue; width: 75px; height: 35px; z-index: 200; font-size: 14px; background-color:#00FF33; }
 


$(function(){
$(".deathWormButton").click(
  function () {
    var htmlStr = $("#pageContent").html();
    $("#DeathWormPage").text(htmlStr);
  }
);
});

 



DeathWorm 


And be one deathWormButton, long I stood  And looked down one as far as I could To where it bent in the undergrowth;
 


ok here-- deathworm button please place content here.
```

Comment: This works as well,,,<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".deathWormButton").click(
  function () {
    $("#DeathWormPage").html($("#pageContent").html());
  }
);
});
</script>

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
$("#pageContent").replaceWith($("#DeathWormPage"));
```

should work as well, and is a little more concise/semantic.